# Consuming Web API in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a Web API (Server) project in ASP.Net Core. Testing it with Postman is successful. Consuming the Web API from an ASP.Net Core Blazor (Client) project is also successful. I was able to display the JSon result in the Razor pages without problems. However, when I created a client project in Xamarin.Forms, I wasn't able to successfully get the JSon results but it gives me an "Error occurred while sending request" and an "InnerException "The text associated with this error code could not be found. The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect". The code I used to consume the API is below:

```
    public async Task<List<Contact>> GetAllDataAsync()
    {
        var Contacts = new List<Contact>();
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.ContactsUrl, string.Empty));

        try
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Contacts;
    }
```

What else did I miss?

Comment: *"The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect"* sounds like an SSL-issue

Comment: If the request address start with **https** , you need to add service supports .Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90195/how-can-i-do-https-requests

Comment: Solved it already. Thanks guys.